# Excluding fields when dynamically creating a pseudo model in Django to initiate a Form

Tags: python, django, django-models

I've been reading up on [Dynamic Models](https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/DynamicModels) and have been trying to create one. I'm creating the model from scratch without the help of any helper functions. The docs point to a helper function called `create_model` which I can't seem to find in Django 1.3. Any ideas, why? Due to this missing helper function, I'm creating the pseudo-model like this:

```
Person = type('Person', (models.Model,), {
    'first_name': models.CharField(max_length=255),
    'last_name': models.CharField(max_length=255),
    '__module__' : 'modules.testmodule'
})
```

This initialised a psuedo-model object and I would like to pass this pseudo Model object to one of my Forms to initialize it.

How can I set the values for the Model fields when initialising it so that the Form can inititialise it's own fields from the Model instance.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This did it:

```
 setattr(Person, 'first_name', 'John')
```